# C# Value cannot be null. Parameter name: user

Tags: c#, connection-string

In my C# application I use 2 connection strings (application_cs, users_cs). To change these connection strings I use:

```
private static void SetProviderConnectionString(string connectionString)
        {
            var connectionStringFieldM =
            Membership.Provider.GetType().GetField("_sqlConnectionString",
                        BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
            var connectionStringFieldR = Roles.Provider.GetType().GetField("_sqlConnectionString",
                       BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
            var connectionStringFieldP = ProfileManager.Provider.GetType().GetField("_sqlConnectionString",
                    BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

            connectionStringFieldM.SetValue(Membership.Provider, connectionString);
            connectionStringFieldR.SetValue(Roles.Provider, connectionString);
            connectionStringFieldP.SetValue(ProfileManager.Provider, connectionString);
        }

        public static void SetProviderUsers()
        {
            SetProviderConnectionString(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["users_cs"].ConnectionString);
        }

        public static void SetProviderApp()
        {
            SetProviderConnectionString(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["application_cs"].ConnectionString);
        }
```

So in my code whenever I want to add a user I do this:

```
public int CreateUser(int stid, int cid, int usrId, string email, string tel, string mob, string username, 
            bool create, bool prime)
        {
            int result = 0; 
            Guid userid = new Guid();
            DALUsers.UserDBDataContext dc = new DALUsers.UserDBDataContext();
            DAL.AppDataContext d = new DAL.AppDataContext();

            BLL.Security.SetProviderUsers();

            if (create) //create the user first
            {

                string question = "1";
                string answer = "1";
                bool isAproved = true;

                string password = System.Web.Security.Membership.GeneratePassword(8, 2);


                MembershipCreateStatus cs = new MembershipCreateStatus();

                MembershipUser newUser = Membership.CreateUser(username, password, email, question, answer, isAproved, out cs);
                Membership.UpdateUser(newUser);
                Roles.AddUserToRole(username, "User_x");
                if (cs == MembershipCreateStatus.Success)
                {
                    result = 1;
                }
                else
                    X.MessageBox.Info("Error", "Cannot create user due to :" + cs.ToString(), UI.Danger).Show();
            }

            //at this point we have the user created either way. 

            // return userid;
            var id = (from i in dc.aspnet_Users where i.UserName.CompareTo(username) == 0 select i.UserId);
            if (id.Count() == 1)
            {
                userid = id.First();
                bool contin = true;
                var fulname = (from i in dc.Clients where i.id == usrId select i).First();

                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(fulname.Mobile)) fulname.Mobile = mob; 

                fulname.Email = email;
                fulname.ModifiedBy = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
                fulname.ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now;

                dc.SubmitChanges();


                DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;

                DALUsers.CIUser usr = new DALUsers.CIUser();

                var existing = (from i in dc.CIUsers where i.UserName.CompareTo(username) == 0 && i.cid == cid select i);
                if (existing.Count() > 0)
                {
                    X.MessageBox.Info("Warning", "UserName already exists . Please try another!", UI.Warning).Show();
                    contin = false;
                }
                else
                {


                    dc.CIUsers.InsertOnSubmit(usr);
                    dc.SubmitChanges();
                }

                if (contin)
                {
                    DALUsers.CIUser usrNew = new DALUsers.CIUser();

                    var approved = (from k in dc.aspnet_Memberships //if user is not approved 
                                    where k.UserId == userid
                                    select k).FirstOrDefault();

                    if (approved.IsApproved == false)
                    {
                        approved.IsApproved = true;
                    }

                    ProfileBase profile = ProfileBase.Create(username);
                    profile.SetPropertyValue("Mobile", mob);
                    profile.SetPropertyValue("Email", email);
                    profile.Save();

                    usrNew.UserId = usrId;
                    usrNew.cid = cid;
                    usrNew.FullName = fulname.LastName + " " + fulname.FirstName;
                    usrNew.Role = "User_x";
                    usrNew.SignRights = prime;
                    usrNew.IsPrime = prime;
                    usrNew.stid = stid;
                    usrNew.UserName = username;
                    usrNew.UserId = userid;
                    usrNew.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
                    usrNew.CreatedBy = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
                    dc.CIUsers.InsertOnSubmit(usrNew);
                    dc.SubmitChanges();

                    result = 1;

                    X.MessageBox.Info("Success", "The user has been successfully added", UI.Success).Show();
                }
            }
            else
                X.MessageBox.Info("Error", "Could not find the user", UI.Danger).Show();
            BLL.Security.SetProviderApp();
            return result;
        }
```

**EDIT**
I just saw that in my code there is this line:

```
DALUsers.aspnet_User user = new DALUsers.aspnet_User();
```

But the variable user is not used anywhere else in the code. Probably it has been left there... And its the only variable named `user` in my code. Is that causing the issue? But then why only on the production server?
**EDIT**

The weird part is that when I run my application from visual studio locally it works as a charm. But when I am adding a user in the application running on the production server when I am trying to add the **second** user it fails and I receive this error:

> Value cannot be null. Parameter name: user

And if I try to login to my application after that it fails. I have to restart my website from iis to be able to login again.
Any ideas?

Comment: "//....code to add users" what is that ? Share these lines

Comment: I don't see any method in your code that would have a parameter named "user". Your error can not be in there.

Comment: creating the user by populating aspnet tables (aspnet_Profile, aspnet_Users, aspnet_UsersInRoles etc... and my table of users in the Users database)

Comment: And, BTW, are you seriously reflecting into private fields to change the behavior of an object? Yuck!

Comment: @Sefe please check my edited post. Info regarding the "user" variable

Comment: First of all, there is still no method with a parameter "user" in your code. An secondly, when you are doing what you're doing (manipulating private fields), all bets are off. You need to find a better way to solve your problem.

Comment: You need to write and add a [mcve] and you **seriously** need to reconsider your coding. You **do not** write to private fields via reflection. You sure *can* but I don't want to do anything with your app other than get a shovel, dumping it on the next trash pile, very carefully, lest I accidentally touch it.

Comment: @nvoigt I added the whole code for adding user

Comment: @Sefe I guess that if there was a null parameter `user` then the application wouldn't run locally either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I cant find the error in your code but if you say that this error occurs only in server and that you are sure that your files are synched between server and your local machine, then probably the error lies in your web.config. Take a look